# Sharing script output via webpage (different servers)

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I've been asked to setup a solution for the following problem:

1. A web page on server "A" take some parameter from the user
2. On server "B", a script run with the parameter from the web page and
   create a bunch of text files on output after 10 minutes
3. After the computation is ended, the results are shown to the user
   who entered the parameters.

Both machine are linux and are connected via a private network.

My idea: create a script on the server "A" which connects via SSH to the server "B", run the script with the parameters, wait for its finish, then copy the files via SCP. The script is invoked from the webpage.

To code the script I would use Python and the Paramiko library to carry out SSH communications.

What to you think of my solution? I would be glad to hear opinions or improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would work.

If both applications are python scripts you could try working with [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

The two applications could communicate directly.